# How to get the value of clicked <td> inside an input field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").on("click", function() {
    var tdval, inputval, editdiv = "";
    editdiv = $('<div class="editdiv"><input type="text" class="input"><button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>');
    if (!$(this).find(".input").length) {
      tdval = $(this).text();
      $(this).html(editdiv);
      $('.input').val(tdval);
      $(".input").focus();
      $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
        inputval = $(".input").val();
        $(this).closest(".editdiv").parent("td").html(inputval);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
thead {
  background: #f05858;
  color: #fff;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tbody td {
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
i {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
button {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dynamic Table</title>
  <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First<i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
          <th>Second</th>
          <th>Third</th>
          <th>Fourth</th>
          <th>Fifth</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to build a dynamic table and I want to have edit option for each `<td>` in each row. But Whenever I click multiple `<td>` to edit I am getting the recent clicked `<td>` value inside all input fields, how to get only the clicked value inside the input using jquery.

Comment: And did you try to use `$(this).closest(".editdiv").find(".input").val();`

Comment: try using this `$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
        inputval = $(this).closest('td').find(".input").val();
        $(this).closest(".editdiv").parent("td").html(inputval);
      });`

Answer (score 3):

The main issue in your code is that you're accessing all the `.input` elements, even when there may be multiple instances. Instead you should use DOM traversal to access only those which are related to the element which raised the event, or to the HTML which is being appended.

Also note that the delegated event handler should not be inside the `click` handler. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").on("click", function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var $editdiv = $('<div class="editdiv"><input type="text" class="input"><button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>');
    
    if (!$td.find(".input").length) {
      var tdText = $td.text();
      $td.html($editdiv);
      $editdiv.find('.input').val(tdText).focus();
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
    var inputval = $(this).prev(".input").val();
    $(this).closest(".editdiv").parent("td").html(inputval);
  });
});
```

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
thead {
  background: #f05858;
  color: #fff;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tbody td {
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
i {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
button {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dynamic Table</title>
  <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First<i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
          <th>Second</th>
          <th>Third</th>
          <th>Fourth</th>
          <th>Fifth</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its working fine.. Thank you for a quick response :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `$('.input').val(tdval);`, because here you are selecting **all** inputs, while you only want the input inside of `editdiv`

So, you just need to add a parent selector to select that specific `input`, like this:

`$('.input', $(this))`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").on("click", function() {
    var tdval, inputval, editdiv = "";
    editdiv = $('<div class="editdiv"><input type="text" class="input"><button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>');
    if (!$(this).find(".input").length) {
      tdval = $(this).text();
      $(this).html(editdiv);
      $('.input', $(this)).val(tdval);
      $('.input', $(this)).focus();
      $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
        inputval = $('.input', $(this).closest(".editdiv")).val();
        $(this).closest(".editdiv").parent("td").html(inputval);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
thead {
  background: #f05858;
  color: #fff;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tbody td {
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
i {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
button {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dynamic Table</title>
  <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First<i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </th>
          <th>Second</th>
          <th>Third</th>
          <th>Fourth</th>
          <th>Fifth</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Click on multiple <td> with different number, when you click on the button in each <td> the last td number will be saved

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce :).. Its working fine.

Comment: @Monasha, thanks for your feedback .. I fixed it now